# Is there a way to distinguish between a renamed file and changed content using Push Notifications?

Tags: google-drive-api

No matter if I rename a file on Google Drive or change the content of the file - in both cases I get the

```
X-Goog-Changed: content,properties
```

header.
Is there a way to find out what exactly has been changed?

Comment: Have you tried checking the Etag?

Comment: In order to get the eTag I have to make an additional drive API request which is quite expensive. But if there is not way to extract the info right from the notification this is what I have to do.

Comment: I suspect the etag will be updated for both meta data and content changes. You might be able to store and compare the md5 sum.